# Angular sends the ID in the request body instead of URL

Tags: angularjs, rest, http, crud

Here is a resource definition:

```
app.factory('Program', ['$resource', function ($resource) {
        return $resource(host + '/rest/program/:id/:action', {}, {query: {method: 'get', isArray: false}});
    }]);
```

When I call `Program.save({id:3,name:'foo'});` it sends request to `POST /rest/program` and places `{id:3,name:'foo'}` in request body. Shouldn't it send the update request to `/rest/program/3` and put only `{name:'foo'}` in the request body.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
app.factory('Program', ['$resource', function ($resource) {
    return $resource(host + '/rest/program/:id/:action', {
        id: '@id',
        action: '@action'
    }, {
        query: {
            method: 'get',
            isArray: false
        }
    });
}]);
```

You might need to pass them as parameters too.

Answer (score 1):

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource

> The action methods on the class object or instance object can be
>   invoked with the following parameters:

```
HTTP GET "class" actions: Resource.action([parameters], [success], [error])
non-GET "class" actions: Resource.action([parameters], postData, [success], [error])
non-GET instance actions: instance.$action([parameters], [success], [error])
```

Since you are using a non-GET action and only passing in a single argument it assumes that it is the `postData` and the optional parameters argument is not supplied.

Use:

```
Program.save({id:3}, {id:3, name:'foo'});
```